# Porque no puedo hacer el update en mi base de datos?

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un proyecto creado en NodeJS y utilizo Mongodb para almacenar mis datos, junto con Joi y Express, el problema aquí es que intento hacer un update y al verificarlo en Postman me regresa un "Bad request" diciendo que requiere un dato que ya le estoy mandando

error en postman:

```
{
"error": {
    "_original": {
        "real_name": "Drake JBell"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "message": "\"artistic_name\" is required",
            "path": [
                "artistic_name"
            ],
            "type": "any.required",
            "context": {
                "label": "artistic_name",
                "key": "artistic_name"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

esta es la manera en la que ingreso los datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora la petición la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
ruta.put('/:real_name', (req, res) =>{
const {error, value} = schema.validate({real_name:req.body.real_name});
if(!error){
    let resultado = actualizarSinger(req.params.real_name, req.body);
    resultado
    .then(user =>{
        res.json({
            valor:user
        })
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(400).json({
            error:err 
        });
    });
}
else{
    res.status(400).json({
        error:error
    });
}
```

});

donde la función que utilizo es "actulaizarSinger":

```
async function actualizarSinger(real_name, body){
let singer = await Singer.findOneAndUpdate({"real_name":real_name}, {
    $set:{
        artistic_name:body.artistic_name,
        real_name:body.real_name,
        nationality:body.nationality
    }
}, {new:true});
return singer;
```

}

pude almacenar un dato que es el que quiero actualizar:

```
{  "_id": {    "$Objectid": "628516d50e10eaca38830a8f"  },  
 "artistic_name": "Drake Campana",  
 "real_name": "Drake ",  
 "nationality": "american",  
 "estado": "true",  "__v": 0}
```

se muestra de esta manera y no puedo observar en donde me falta el dato para que no se actualice, presiento que tal vez el error esta en ruta.put

schema:
const schema = Joi.object({
artistic_name:Joi.string()
.min(3)
.max(15),
real_name:Joi.string()
.min(3)
.max(20),
nationality:Joi.string()
.min(3)
.max(10)
});

Comment: Es un error de escritura, estás enviando `artisitic_name` (tiene una `i` de más)

Comment: lo corregí, me sigue regresando la bad request :c

Comment: pero debe ser con un error distinto, con cual te manda error ahora?
Tambien podría ser problema del nombre: Ensaya cambiar el nombre en la URL de POSTMAN por `Drake%20Campana`

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "_original": {
            "real_name": "Drake JBell"
        },
        "details": [
            {
                "message": "\"artistic_name\" is required",
                "path": [
                    "artistic_name"
                ],
                "type": "any.required",
                "context": {
                    "label": "artistic_name",
                    "key": "artistic_name"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: sigue siendo el mismo error :c
también trate cambiando la URL de postman, e igual sucede lo mismo, por eso estoy tan confundido

Comment: Si al inicio de la funcion pones `console.log(req.body)` si tiene datos? si estas usando el middelware de bodyparser?

Comment: Y puedes agregar como tienes definido el `schema`?

Comment: ya agregue el schema amigo!, y tenias razón era eso, definí que el artistic_name sea requerido, se lo quite y ya me dejo modificar

Comment: Por favor, pongan la solución como respuesta, así otros sabrán cómo lo resolvieron :)

Comment: claro que si!, pero al parecer debo esperar 48 horas para poder responderlo yo mismo, o se puede hacer de otra manera?

Comment: no.. tenes que esperar 48 horas para poder aceptar tu respuesta.. la respuesta, la podes escribir inmediatamente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error era en el schema el cual era:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
artistic_name:Joi.string()
                    .min(3)
                    .max(15)
                    .required(),
real_name:Joi.string()
                .min(3)
                .max(20),
nationality:Joi.string()
                .min(3)
                .max(10)
```

ya que como muestra en la imagen regresaba el mensage de 'artistic_name required', y claro en el mismo schema esta requerido

simplemente se borro el required y el update se puede hacer sin problema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
artistic_name:Joi.string()
                    .min(3)
                    .max(15),
real_name:Joi.string()
                .min(3)
                .max(20),
nationality:Joi.string()
                .min(3)
                .max(10)
```

Comment: genial, no olvides aceptar tu respuesta al dia siguiente

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado mi idea. Considera hacer "upvote" (o flechita arriba) a los comentarios que te fueron útiles. Saludos.